# Zend framework 2 Rest API : Calls getList() instead of get($id) function

Tags: php, rest, zend-framework2, zend-rest

Following is my module config file

```
return array(
'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'RSMobile\Controller\User' => 'RSMobile\Controller\UserController',
    ),
),

// Routes for API calls
'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(

        'rsmobile' => array(
            'type' => 'segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/rsmobile',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'RSMobile\Controller\User',
                )
            ),

            // Child routes
            'child_routes' => array(
                // Route for "user" API
                'user' => array(
                    'type' => 'segment',
                    'options' => array(
                        'route' => '/user[/:id]',
                        'constraints' => array(
                                               'id'     => '[0-9a-zA-Z]+',
                                                              ),
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'controller' => 'RSMobile\Controller\User',
                        )
                    ),
                ),
          )
```

Question:

I have extends AbstractRestfulController in UserController file but, when i call this with  www.example.com/rsmobile/user?userid=1 it call **get-list** instead of **get.**

Any Light on path would be helpful

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use `www.example.com/rsmobile/user?userid=1` pattern only and not `www.example.com/rsmobile/user/1`.

In `AbstractRestfulController`,  `$identifierName` is set to `id`, by default. If it does not find `id` in list of params then it will call `getList()` method. So what you can do is in your controller(which must be extending `AbstractRestfulController`) write below code :

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->identifierName = 'userId'; // Override $identifierName value specified in AbstractRestfulController.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What I understand is that the request is matching your `/rsmobile/` route instead of `/rsmobile/user` route. is that it?

I don't know how you deal with the paramater `userid` but probably, you don't need it, and instead of `www.example.com/rsmobile/user?userid=1` you can call `www.example.com/rsmobile/user/1`  that will match your route, and will give you an id parameter in your controller.

Also, I think you are missing the `'may_terminate' => true` int the child route. Probably you  should be:

```
        // Child routes
        'child_routes' => array(
            // Route for "user" API
            'user' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                 'may_terminate' => true,
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/user[/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                                           'id'     => '[0-9a-zA-Z]+',
                                                          ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'RSMobile\Controller\User',
                    )
                ),
            ),
```

Comment: Actually i want to use /user?userId=1 instead of user/1 and when use that method it call's getList() and if call like /user?userId=1&id=0 then it call get() ,is it that we have to use 'id'?

Comment: The answer of @akash is what you need!